# Mac OS X Snow Leopard: How to connect to a windows \\share?

Tags: windows, macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard, network-shares

How do I connect from Snow Leopard to a `\\server\folder` location on a windows server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command-K (or the "Connect to Server..." menu item) in finder.  Then type:

```
smb://server/folder
```

Presto!

(And this question belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this from the command line, you can do:

```
open smb://server/share
```

or

```
open cifs://server/share
```

You can access this by then navigating to /Volumes

```
cd /Volumes/share
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to enable SMB sharing in the sharing settings. That is, if you intend to go both ways.

If you are serious about working in a dinamic mixed environment, try a third party solution such as http://www.koingosw.com/products/swiftshare.php

I wish it would all just work.

Answer (score 0):

I need to do this quite often, and i use a great piece of freeware called WinShortcutter: http://www.lobotomo.com/products/WinShortcutter/index.html

The best thing about this is that you can select the UNC path (eg `\\server\folder`) and open directly with a keyboard shortcut. You can also rightclick a network folder and copy a path to the clipboard (useful for sending to Windows colleagues).

Finally, you can set up mappings so that when someone sends you a path to `S:\folder\`, it will open the correct folder on the server.